# AutoMapper UseValue, ResolveUsing or MapFrom reusing value from previous call. Is it caching or something?

Tags: ajax, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, generic-collections

I have a situation where starting from the 2nd call and subsequent ones (Ajax GET calls), `AutoMapper` is reusing the previous value (the value from the 1st call that comes from a click in an action link). It's like a "caching" problem...

```
public virtual ActionResult List(int assessmentId, int? chapterId, bool? isMenuClick)
{

    Mapper.CreateMap<Element, AssessmentQuestionViewModel>().
    ForMember(dest => dest.AssessmentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => assessmentId));

    ...

}
```

It doesn't matter if I use `UseValue`, `ResolveUsing` or `MapFrom` in the above `opt =>` lambda. The behavior is the same, that is, it reuses the value from previous calls.

`AssessmentId` property does not exist in the source type ( `Element` ). This way I try to assign `AssessmentId` a value that "may" change dynamically during subsequent calls to the method where I have this code. `assessmentId` is a parameter in my ASP.NET MVC action method as shown above in the method signature.

Then I call this code in the `List` action method:

```
var questions =
    Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Element>, IEnumerable<AssessmentQuestionViewModel>>
     (Database.Elements.Where(e => !elementIds.Contains(e.ElementId) &&
                              e.Standard.ChapterId == chapterId));
```

The first time, `questions` is OK, that is, all `AssessmentQuestionViewModel` objects have the `AssessmentId` property set correctly as per the `CreateMap` defined.

Starting from the 2nd call, it reuses the `assessmentId` from the 1st call and it messes up with my business logic because I expect it to map `AssessmentId` to the updated `assessmentId` that's being passed as a parameter to the `List` method.

Just to be sure: I've set a breakpoint in the code and I can see that the value of the `assessmentId` parameter is correct. It's just the returned mapped objects `questions` that have the wrong value in the `AssessmentId` property - a value that differs from the current `assessmentId` value. The values should be equal as I understand it since I'm asking AutoMapper to do the mapping using that current value.

I have AutoMapper 2.2.1-ci9000 (Prerelease), but I tested this with the previous version and I saw this same behavior. I updated to the Prerelease thinking that this "misbehavior" would go away.

I think this is a bug. Please correct me if I'm wrong or if I'm trying to use it in a way not supported. :)

Comment: CreateMap is supposed to be called once per AppDomain - not in your controller action. It's not that it's cached - but that it's not re-configured every. single. time.

Comment: @JimmyBogard So in my specific case what's the path I should follow? I'll have to manually set that specific property in the Destination object every single time the action method is called? Right now I use a simple `foreach`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here your trying to create multiple mappings of the same type - which AutoMapper doesn't support. Everytime your `List` action is called, you create a new mapping (which has a different `ForMember(...)` clause). AutoMapper won't throw an exception it just ignores the duplicate mapping so what you are seeing here isn't a bug, it's expected behaviour.

`ForMember` is infact called on *every* map, however, you have a scoping issue here as your variable is hard-coded into the expression. As a work-around you could do something like:

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController()
    {
        // define mapping once, but make assessment expression dynamic
        Mapper.CreateMap<Element, AssessmentQuestionViewModel>().
            ForMember(dest => dest.AssessmentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => GetCurrentAssessmentId()));
    }

    private int GetCurrentAssessmentId()
    {
        return (int)TempData["AssessmentId"];
    }

    public ActionResult List(int assessmentId, ...)
    {
        // store current assessment temporarily
        TempData.Add("AssessmentId", assessmentId);
        // execute mapping
        var questions = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Element>, IEnumerable<AssessmentQuestionViewModel>>
 (Database.Elements.Where(e => !elementIds.Contains(e.ElementId) &&
                          e.Standard.ChapterId == chapterId));
    }
}
```

I will say though, your jumping through a lot of hoops for this to work, it would be much simpler to manually set the property without the help of AutoMapper e.g.

```
var questions = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Element>, IEnumerable<AssessmentQuestionViewModel>>(...);
foreach (var q in questions)
{
    q.AssessmentId = assessmentId;
}
```

Comment: Uhmmm... I think I understand what you're saying. So, do you have any idea how I should approach this mapping? I need to assign the dynamic value to `Mapper.CreateMap`. According to you, I must define the `CreateMap` only once. Maybe I can do: `if(!isMenuClick.HasValue) { // CreateMap since it's the first call to the action method }`, then for subsequent calls (Ajax ones) I just call `Mapper.Map`.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi see my update. The goal here is to make the assessment Id dynamic for the initial mapping (so there is no hard-coded expressions). A simple way of doing this is to return it from a function.

Comment: that's what I have right now. I just set the value using the `foreach` approach. I posted the question just to know why that first approach wasn't working. Your answer shed some light! Thanks my friend... :)

Comment: @LenielMacaferi like I have illustrated it *can* be done, the question is - is it worth the extra effort? Personally, for a single property, I would say no :)

Comment: Exactly. I also think it's not worth the effort. We followed the easy path/the same approach in this case. :)